# Error contacting the Parsoid/RESTBase server: http-bad-status on Fresh Mediawiki 1.35.0 LTS

Tags: mediawiki

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki_1.35 is out and one of the advertise features seems to be the "built in"/"out of the box" Visual Editor that doesn't need an external server anymore.

So downloaded and installed the version just released and clicked "VisualEditor" so that it would appear in my LocalSettings.php as:

```php
wfLoadExtension( 'VisualEditor' );
```

But when trying to edit a page the error message:

```
Error contacting the Parsoid/RESTBase server: http-bad-status
```

With no further hint on what to do.

The information in https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:VisualEditor is still intimidating for me - it doesn't look like an "out of the box" configuration at all. I did not find anything there about the dialog's message content.

**Where do i find the official information on how to avoid this dialog?**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The extension should work out of the box on 1.35. Make sure you do NOT have any Parsoid / RESTBase related configuration. Also make sure you are actually using 1.35 - master is configured differently.

Comment: Specifically, make sure `$wgVirtualRestConfig` is not set.

Comment: so far i removed the extension from the Localsettings.php to work around the issue.

Comment: @WolfgangFahl did you ever solve this issue, other than disabling the extension? I've tried this install on a fresh Ubuntu box with MW 1.38 and still the same issue persists!

Comment: @nadsy I never tried again. I am getting used to these kinds of quirks of software provided by the MediaWiki Foundation. Every once in a while i file bug reports and they might or might not be resolved. There is IMHO no way to influence the priorities by us mere mortals.

Comment: @WolfgangFahl - thanks for letting me know. I might save time (and sanity) and disable the feature for now too in that case too.

Comment: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T88016 is the main showstopper for me at this point and i have not accepted any answer yet since Where do i find the official information on how to avoid this dialog? isn't answered yet.

Answer (score 5):

**I've managed to wake up visual editor on an apache / ubuntu with mediawiki 1.37 set to private wiki.**

This is what I've done

```
$wgServer = "https://example.org";
```

Note the https in wgServer!

End of my  LocalSettings.php

```
if ( isset( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ) &&
     in_array( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], [ $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'], '127.0.0.1' ] ) ) {
  $wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = true;
  $wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit'] = true;
  $wgGroupPermissions['*']['writeapi'] = true;
}
```

Comment: The right answer! Besides the extension activation snippet, this is all that's needed, and nothing further in webserver config. Nice and centralized.

Answer (score 3):

Making sure that $wgServer in LocalSettings.php has https and not http in the string solved it for me.

Comment: that sounds interesting ... might be a classical documentation gap ...

Comment: I changed my question for the official documentation question. Is there a phabricator task for this in the meantime?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the HTTP based authentication of your webserver you have to allow localhost to be whitelisted, so MediaWiki can reach itself.

For Apache you can do this with

```
Require local
```

at the same spot where you configured the authentication. You can find detailed configuration descriptions in the MediaWiki Wiki.

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:Vwkv6abtipmknci8

However i would not recommend to use whitelisting based on the user agent. Attackers could circumvent the authentication just by changing their user agent string.

Comment: I am not looking for a workaround but the official solution by the MediaWiki foundation . I assume it is documented somewhere.

Comment: It is not a workaround. MediaWiki is not expecting HTTP-based authentication to be in front of the API of the visual editor, so you have to whitelist the API if you use authentication.

Comment: You are pointing to a talk page, not the documentation. So it doesn't run out of the box yet although this is an LTS version. I 'll rather wait for the next LTS or the docs.

Comment: It's not MediaWiki that is blocking the connection. It's the webserver preventing unauthenticated access to localhost. So you either have to equip MediaWiki with credentials (which would have to be implemented) or you allow MediaWiki unauthenticated access, which i described above. Of course it would be possible to not use the API at all, but i think it's unlikely that they will drop their advertised new feature.

Comment: Still this needs to be documented in the official docs and not here. I changed my question accordingly.

Comment: @lalu I cannot thank you enough for pointing this out, as it lead me to realise I had some IP whitelisting in place that was blocking these requests. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I only run into this problem, when I use a "nested" or structured wiki page.

It works for pages like
TestPage, VideoCut, BestPractices    but not pages like

TestPage/Test1, TestPage/Hugo and so on.

When looking at the webserver log page it seams the rest.php URL is not build correctly.

In the good case the build rest.php send the following POST request:

```
POST /wiki/rest.php/localhost/v3/transform/html/to/wikitext/TestPage/12 HTTP/1.1" 200 521 "-" "VisualEditor-MediaWiki/1.38.2"
```

In the bad case the request looks like:

```
POST /wiki/rest.php/localhost/v3/transform/html/to/wikitext/TestPage%2FTest1 HTTP/1.1" 404 981 "-" "VisualEditor-MediaWiki/1.38.2"
```

It ends-up in a 404 instead of a successful 200. The problem seams to be the coded **%2F (/)** inside the Page-Path (TestPage/Test1 -> TestPage%2FTest1).